# Swift - Xcode 8.3 auto complete not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Prior to working on the current project, I didn't really have much trouble with Xcode autocomplete.  In fact, even when I worked on different but much smaller project, Xcode autocomplete and code highlighting worked well.

However, on the current project I am working on, Xcode doesn't show the standard auto complete with all the methods and variables I can use.  It may be of interest that I used GitHub to download the current project on my machine and the project uses a few Pods.  Surprisingly, when I was making some changes to one of the Pods last week, autocomplete worked fine in the Pod file but the autocomplete doesn't (and didn't) show in the source files of the actual project.  Also I am sure that Indexing is turned on (I turned it on in the terminal and I can see the code being indexed when I start).
What I have tried so far (unsuccessfully):

**Method 1**

Delete derived data, restart Xcode, clean project and build.

**Method 2**

In the build settings, set **Always Search User Paths** to **Yes**

In regards to similar questions such as: [Xcode 8.2 Code Completion Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227787/xcode-8-2-code-completion-not-working), my issue is different because my issue isn't exclusive to scope of extension and none of the answers on that page helped me.

**Picture example:**
[image: This is from **another** project where autocomplete works **correctly**. This is what I **WANT**]

This is (picture above) from **another** project where autocomplete works **correctly**.  This is what I **WANT**.  Also note how the instance variable shadowBaseView is highlighted in turquoise.

[image]

Unfortunately the picture on the bottom is what I get when I press **CMD+Space**.  Also in my current project while classes like UIView are highlighted purple, instance variables are still black.

Comment: I get this sometimes and I just reboot my computer to fix it.

Comment: I frequently get have the same issue (and many other XC problems) and I can usually fix it by restarting XCode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8.2 Code Completion Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227787/xcode-8-2-code-completion-not-working)

Comment: @CodeBender I tried restarted Xcode and my Mac but that didn't fix it or help it.

Comment: @Pheepster Read comment above

Comment: @the4kman I have looked at the answer on that thread/question, however that isn't my issue because I am not working inside an extension.

Comment: @Jay Not much I can add, just that I see this issue about once a week in XCode, and restarting the computer (no other actions) fixes it for me.

Answer (score 3):

This tends to happen a lot when switching applications.
Sometimes you have to wait like 6 seconds for the autocomplete to show up.

Try cleaning your code    `CMD+SHIFT+K`
Try building your code    `CMD+SHIFT+B`
Also try running it     `CMD+R`

If it still doesn't work, just restart Xcode. It should work!

Comment: I have done all those things.  It doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

http://theapplady.net/swift-autocomplete/

Example in swift.

Moreover: Clean -> Build.[image]

Comment: Did you try as is told in example over this screenshot? Compare to your steps :)

Comment: Tried yesterday and then I tried it again just now.  Still doesn't work. :(